# How to return specified fields when use linq query in cosmos db sdk

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am using CosmosDb .net sdk v3.
I would like to return only particular fields from documents (basically I need only ids).
In case of GetItemQueryIterator I can specify query like `"SELECT c._id FROM c WHERE ..."`

Is it possible to select only specified fields in case of GetItemLinqQueryable ?
GetItemLinqQueryable has generic parameter, but I assume that it only influences on the serialization, so full document will be returned from db to my code.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your query looks correct based on the docs: https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/03-querying_in_azure_cosmosdb.html#dot-and-quoted-property-projection-accessors

Comment: Will a LINQ select not do what you want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-linq-to-sql